# Which of these is ground, neutral and live?

Tags: electrical

[image: wiring]

I'm installing an electrical fan where a light used to be and the wiring isn't color coded. It looks like the center is a common ground (it was unused in the light) and the sole wire is live (it had a white wire with a black strip) while the rightmost two wires are neutral (they had a white wire attached). Am I correct?

Thank you.

Comment: I seriously doubt that center thing has anything to do with grounds....

Answer (score 4):

### There is no ground here

From the vintage of your wiring, I can tell you that that center bundle has nothing to do with ground, that much is certain!  Instead, what you have here is an incoming mains feed which joins to an outgoing mains feed and a *switch loop* for the light.  As a result, the left is indeed switched-hot, the center *always-hot*, and the right neutral, which explains why the center wire group was not connected to the light.